# How to style ASP.NET DataPager ellipsis

Tags: asp.net, datapager, ellipsis

I'm using DataPager to paginate a ListView, and I set ButtonCount property for NumericPagerField as, say, 5 to limit the maximum count of page numbers to be displayed to 5. But by doing that, when there's more than 5 pages it shows 1 or 2 ellipses (...). Is there any way to style these ellipses or make them dissappear?

Edit: I want to clarify this a bit. What I want to do is hiding the ellipsis in the DataPager when total number of pages exceeds the ButtonCount property (probably by styling display:none but I can't find a way to set css style for it). Please see the image below

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<asp:DataPager ID="datapager" PageSize="16" PagedControlID="someId" runat="server"
                QueryStringField="page">
                ...
                <Fields>
                    <asp:NumericPagerField RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="false" NumericButtonCssClass="someClass other"
                        CurrentPageLabelCssClass="someClass current" ButtonCount="4" />
                </Fields>
                ...
            </asp:DataPager>
```

As you can see, I have set css class for numeric buttons and page label, but it doesn't apply for the ellipsis. So I can't select the ellipsis in my stylesheet. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set NextPreviousButtonCssClass attribute of NumericPagerField to a CSS class to hide ellipsis as below -

CSS -

```
.nextPreviousButtonCSS
{
    display: none;
}
```

ASP.NET -

```
<Fields>
    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowNextPageButton="false"
        ShowPreviousPageButton="true" ButtonCssClass="ButtonCSS" />
    <asp:NumericPagerField RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="false" NumericButtonCssClass="someClass other"
        NextPreviousButtonCssClass="nextPreviousButtonCSS" CurrentPageLabelCssClass="someClass current"
        ButtonCount="4" />
    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false"
        ShowNextPageButton="true" ButtonCssClass="ButtonCSS" />
</Fields>
```

**Note**: You need to add next and previous buttons manually as above with NextPreviousPagerField tag.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for replying but this is not really what I'm looking for. I want to hide the ellipsis in the DataPager when total number of pages exceeds the ButtonCount property (probably by styling display:none but I can't find a way to set css style for it). Do you have any idea?

Comment: CAn you please provide code snippet and screenshot? I will help to explain the requirement.

Comment: I have added some further info above. Please have a look :)

Comment: Modified the answer above. Please check.